# Is it a good idea to implement Function and Buffer in a single class?

Tags: java, function, hadoop, buffer, cascading

I want to know of a situation where I could implement `cascading.operation.Buffer`, `cascading.operation.Function` and perform operation on tuples.

```
public class Hello extends BaseOperation implements Buffer, Function {

}
```

I am not sure if the above class will work or not.

**If it works then which operate method will be called?**

Any practical scenarios where I should implement it? Any Performance issues?

Comment: Where do you get the `BaseOperation` class, `Buffer` and `Function` interfaces from? What packages? What is your actual question?

Comment: I am talking about Cascading API.
http://docs.cascading.org/cascading/1.2/javadoc/cascading/operation/BaseOperation.html

Answer (score 0):

The interfaces you are talking about are:

- [`cascading.operation.Buffer<C>`](http://docs.cascading.org/cascading/1.2/javadoc/cascading/operation/Buffer.html)
- [`cascading.operation.Function<C>`](http://docs.cascading.org/cascading/1.2/javadoc/cascading/operation/Function.html)

They indeed both have an `operate()` method, but the methods have different parameter signatures, more specifically:

- `void operate(FlowProcess flowProcess,`**`BufferCall<C>`**`bufferCall)`
  for **`Buffer`**
- `void operate(FlowProcess flowProcess,`**`FunctionCall<C>`**`functionCall)` for **`Function`**

The common superinterface of those two (i.e. `Operation<C>`) that is used in `BaseOperation<C>` class has nothing to do with `operate()` method, as it's only defined in the subinterfaces.

---

So to answer *which `operate()` method will be called*:

**Depends on the type of second parameter that's passed to the method.**